# POST http://localhost:8000/login 419 (unknown status) laravel+sanctum+vuejs

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

My Vuejs app doesn't set cookie headers.I am running my laravel app on port 8000 and my vuejs app on port 8080 and I use fortify for authentication. My vuejs app is not in same directory as my laravel app
Also in Network tab of chrome this error appears this attempt to set a cookie was blocked because samesite=lax.
These are my configurations.
.env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8080
```

cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', '/sanctum/csrf-cookie','/login','/register'],    
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],    
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],    
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],    
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],    
    'exposed_headers' => [],    
    'max_age' => 0,    
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Vue js

I am new to Vue and I know this isn't the best way to use axios but for now i am just trying to be able to login.

```
async login() {
      try {
        this.token = await axios.get("//localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie",{
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        this.result = await axios.post(
          "//localhost:8000/login",
          { email: this.email, password: this.password },
          {
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        );

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  }
```

For two days I have read every post on stackoverflow regarding this issue but I still haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: The problem is, they are running on different ports, which from the browsers view have their own security policy. Service on port 8000 cannot speak for service on port 8080. My personal solution is to run them through the same reverse proxy so they have the same domain and port. There are other ways tho, which I'll leave open to whom who want to post an answer :-)

Comment: could you please comment a useful link to your solution so I use it as well

Comment: I am using nginx. nginx can talk to PHP FPM or any HTTP server. So you have nginx server and just need to take care of the path mapping (example: You request http://localhost/login, you need to tell nginx if it should forward that to the node server or to the laravel server). This is the [official nginx admin guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to reverse proxy.